# How to display count of user registered for particular event or item in recyclerview and display on textview in android?

Tags: php, android

I'm creating an event app which consists of all events. These events are stored in the MySQL database and displayed in recyclerview. Now user can click on the event and register it. I want to show the count of how many users are registered for that particular event on textview below each event in recyclerview.

I had written code in PHP for getting the count for each event. But I'm not able to show on textview using the volley POST method. It's showing 0 counts for all event though it is registered by many users. I tried in POSTMAN to see whether PHP code is wrong or not but it's working and showing the perfect result in postman just can't able to show on textview.

Code in php DbOperation:

```
  public function TotalRecords($eventid){
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM econfirm WHERE eventid = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s",$eventid);
                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    return  $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

                }
                else
                {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
```

**Count.php**

```
   <?php 
    require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
    $response = array(); 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if(
            isset($_POST['eventid'])) 
            {
            //operate the data further 

            $db = new DbOperations(); 

            $user = $db->TotalRecords($_POST['eventid']);
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['countid'] = $user['COUNT(id)'];

            if($user == 1){
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = "Success";
            }elseif($user == 2){
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = "error";         
            }elseif($user == 0){
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = "Nodata";                        
            }

        }else{
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
        }
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

**Show count on textview**

```
 total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_COUNT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                           total.setText(jsonObject.getString("countid"));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("eventid", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

[getting count as json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMx0A.png)

Comment: Show your code what you tryed

Comment: total.setText(jsonObject.getString("countid")); This line is used to display count from database to textview but still its not working.

Comment: Do you get the correct `JSONObject` ?

Comment: Yes, when I run PHP file in postman it's giving a correct count for each event. I think there is no problem with PHP code as it's giving proper json . just that it's not displaying on textview.You can see the image attached.

Comment: I had able to bring count number of each event. It's displaying correctly for second events onwards but it's not displaying for first event only. So I'm not getting what is the problem.

Comment: Finally!! it is solved. Count for each event is perfectly displaying.